# How to set current date time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am getting date in the following format :

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 21:30:00 GMT +0530(IST)
```

I want to that time will remain and I can change date to the current date like :

```
Mon Dec 14 2015 21:30:00 GMT +0530(IST)
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: What is your purpose of doing this? What is the logic of this changing? Please add some code to understand the question

Comment: Thanks for reply Dinidu.  Actually i am using time picker. and i need to set time for notifications. But i get time in the formate as i mentioned but i need the current date as i am getting past date. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't understand. Both formats looks the same to me. Can you write what datetime picker you're using?

Comment: You can see. I got past date in result but need current date. @tiriana

Comment: I think your server is not in the same region, you are. It gives you the server current time and date. Time zone mismatch is the reason for this problem. You have to address this in a different way.

Comment: @user3884692, I see those dates have different values, but their formats are the same. Sorry, I still don't get what is the actual problem. Your time picker returns  ```Thu Jan 01 1970 21:30:00 GMT +0530(IST)``` even when you click some other date?

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Comment: Yes you are right @tiriana

Comment: actually i need to get the current year and day.

Comment: I means is there way i merge these two dates to get current date and time ? Means time from the past date and year & day from current ?

Answer (score 4):

Reading the comments I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. Try this:

```
var oldDate = new Date("Thu Jan 01 1970 21:30:00 GMT +0530(IST)");
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setHours(oldDate.getHours());
newDate.setMinutes(oldDate.getMinutes());
newDate.setSeconds(oldDate.getSeconds());
```

Then `newDate` should contain the date you desire.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the Date Object. Use something like below to get custom one.

```
date.getDay() + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getFullYear()
```

Reference URL:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp

Answer (score -1):

Use `new Date();`

Also have a look at : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: This is not an answer. Please do not recommend or link to w3schools. Far better to link to [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for examples.